# How to properly parse JSON into usable output (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, xml, formatting

**I'm using an API that I call with something like this:**

**Controller:**

```
@bounces = SendgridToolkit::Bounces.new(API_USERNAME, API_PASSWORD)
```

**View:**

**And that returns data like this: (for JSON, though an XML call is also possible)**

```
[{"status"=>"550", "created"=>2015-07-06 18:37:38 UTC, "reason"=>"550 Unrouteable address ", "email"=>"jake@fake.com"}]
```

It's useful to me, but unfortunately it's not the way I want to present it in my Rails application. What's the best way to transform this data, since I don't have access to the poorly formatted string itself, only the code that requests it from the application I'm interacting with?

I'm having some issues coming up with the right question to ask Google, and would appreciate any suggestions you have to offer from experience.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**EDIT:**

For example, this returns an error no matter where I put it (The view or the controller), saying that string is an undefined method:

```
 string = '[{"status":"550","reason":"550 Unrouteable address ","email":"jake@fake.com"}]'
    @showbounces = @bounces.retrieve.to_json JSON.parse(string)
    @newsletters = Newsletter.all
```

**returns:**

```
no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer:

@showbounces = @bounces.retrieve.to_json JSON.parse(string)
```

Ultimately I'd like to extract select information from the JSON/XML and use it for things like graphs in my view that I can format with CSS and HTML.

Comment: ok, got more questions than answers atm. Firstly, where do you call an API? I assume `retrieve_with_timestamps` makes the call? Now, how do you know the return is an actual string and not an array of hashes? Your edit section is a riddle as well - if you dind;t defined string variable why do you expect it to work?

Comment: @BroiStatse Sorry, I'm completely new to working with API's in Rails, and, indeed, Rails in general. I edited the question to show what I've put up there now. I though that `string` was defined in Ruby already (hence why `.to_s` works), and I guess the wording of the resource I found confused me a bit. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to parse the JSON output string from the web service. The `SendgridToolkit` gem takes care of that. It returns the data as Ruby objects (arrays and/or hashes), ready to be used in your code.

For example, in your controller:

```
def index
  bounces = SendgridToolkit::Bounces.new(API_USERNAME, API_PASSWORD)
  @all_bounces = bounces.retrieve
end
```

and then in your view:

```
<ul>
  <% @all_bounces.each do |bounce| %>
    <li>Bounced <%= bounce['email'] %> (<%= bounce['reason'] %>)</li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Well there's my problem then hahahaha. Problem now is that that returns `Bounced ()` when `<%= @all_bounces %>` returns `[{"status"=>"550", "reason"=>"550 Unrouteable address ", "email"=>"jake@fake.com"}]`

Comment: nevermind, it was fixed by passing the `email` and `reason` as a string rather than a key (I believe that terminology is correct for what I'm trying to describe at least). I needed to change your code to look like `<%= bounce["email"] %>` instead of `<%= bounce[:email] %>`. Please edit your answer and I will mark it as accepted right away! Thank you for your insight!

Comment: I'm also running into issues with `SendgridToolkit::Statistics` saying my "delievered" as well as "bounces" etc are all 0, when I know that to be false. Do you have any experience with that? I'd hate for all that information to be useless

Comment: I edited the answer to use strings instead of symbols for the `bounce` hash. Thanks for correcting my error. ;)

Comment: For your statistics issue, it's hard to tell without more info. Maybe double-check your API username & key, if you have different ones for development & production. Maybe there's a delay on the provider's side... (I haven't actually used it yet.)

Comment: I just needed to pass a period to check (date range) with my request. For example, `statistics.retrieve_aggregate` works well to aggregate ALL statistics.